# Send email without opening the website

Tags: javascript, php, email

How can send email like a reminder for a user without opening the website and load the pages

I have a reminder section the user choose the date for his reminder in this date an email will be send to user and this should work without loading the website page

How to do that ? it's possible in php only or i need for example to javascript? and if i need it How to do it ?!

this is the php code for send an email i use

```
   $date=date("Y-m-d");
    include("includes/connect.php");
   $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_staff where db_rem='1' and db_asd >= now()")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $mytask=$row['db_mytask'];
        $name=$row['db_name'];
        $user=$row['db_user'];
        $asd=$row['db_asd'];
        $asdf=strtotime($asd);
        $asdformat = date( 'Y-m-d',$asdf);
        $id=$row['db_id'];
        $user_query=mysqli_query($conn,"select db_email from tbl_user where db_username='$user' limit 1")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $res=mysqli_fetch_array($user_query);
        $email=$res['db_email'];

    $to=$email;
    $subject='Reminder TASK';
    $headers='';
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";  
    $headers .= "From:T-SQUARE.complaints@ts-lb.com" . "\r\n" ;
    $headers .="Reply-To:T-SQUARE.complaints@ts-lb.com" . "\r\n" ;
    $headers .="X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();    
    $message="$name Check this task $mytask PLEASE CHECK IT ON www.eiwms-progroup.com";
    $mail=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"update tbl_staff set db_rem='2'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Google *Scheduled Cron Jobs*

Comment: Note that using a job scheduler like cron is not possible with your current code as there is no concept of user sessions when you call a script from the command line.

Comment: @HankyPanky How to use corn jobs in php ??

Comment: A cronjob is set on the server itself. tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto You can issue commands which repeat every X seconds/minutes/hours. You can for example set a PHP file as target. Place whatever you want to execute in that PHP file.

Comment: @Hespen i use godaddy server than i should install cron jobs on it first !!

Comment: By Googling it again

Comment: Google `godaddy cronjobs`

Comment: @HankyPanky please if you can help me in this after googling i go to my host enter to the cron jobs i have a field name email this cron jobs send to this email but i want to send to user email and this different for each user and for the date will be also different the user will choose this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should just store reminder tasks not in SESSION, but in DB - in this case your could use crontab to run task-handler which will check if any task should be ran for now and will run them if needed. SESSION data is not visible from crontab-launched script, but DB data could be veseble from anywhere.

Comment: can you please check above i update my code and i did a cron jobs in my server i have put an image for it  it's that correct

Comment: better check date directly in your query, instead of get all tasks and then filter them in php. just add `AND db_asd <= now()` to your WHERE condition

Comment: I've update my query please check above any thing else

Comment: and second - as you can see in my comment, you should check date not like `now() = db_asd`, but like `now() >= asd`, because in first case your script will run task only if it check tasks exactly in 00:00, that is practicalli impossible :)

Comment: you've broken a code markup, it is unreadable now :(

Comment: please check above

Comment: and you better run your script, real test would check it much better than someone who you ask to check :)

Comment: you dont need this more  `if($asd==$date){` , you've filtered records in query already

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128346/discussion-between-m7md-and-alexandrx).

Comment: everything else seems to be correct, but I repeat - real test is the best ;)